# Select that looks up a name in another table

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner-join

So I need to list all people in a table of people. Each row has an `office_id`, and when someone is assigned to an office, it contains a value greater than 0 which I need to lookup in the offices table to get the name of the office assigned to the person. But when I use an `INNER JOIN` it ignores the records where the `office_id = 0`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM personnel 
WHERE building_id=$SESSION[building_id] 
ORDER BY last_name 
INNER JOIN offices 
WHERE offices.office_id=personnel.office_id
```

Right now it is giving me everyone that has an assigned office but is ignoring those people (Jill) who have no assigned office. How can I get them ALL to appear like below:

```
Jack Building1 Office1<br>
John Building1 Office2<br>
Jill Building1 <br>
Judy Building1 Office3<br>
Jenn Building1 Office4<br>
```

Comment: Use a LEFT join instead of an inner join.  OUTER Joins allow you to get all data from one or the other table or both tables...   Good examples here: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Surely a complete syntax disaster

Comment: True.  SELECT FROM INNER JOIN WHERE ORDER BY.  Only 1 where per select.

Comment: What table is building_ID sourced?  If offices our LEFT outer join may need to move the where clause to be a compound AND on the join itself or we will negate the values of the left join; making it behave like an inner.

Comment: Thank for your help. That solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I arranged the SQL for correct order of statements and annotated where the other statements would be if used, and switched a WHERE to an on clause for a LEFT join which will include all personnel and only those records in offices that match.

```
SELECT * 
FROM personnel p
LEFT JOIN offices  o
  ON  o.office_id=p.office_id
-- and o.building_id=$SESSION[building_id] --this if building is in offices. and eliminate next
WHERE building_id=$SESSION[building_id] 
--  GROUP BY
--  HAVING
ORDER BY p.last_name 
--  LIMIT
```

Note when using more than one table, it's wise to alias the tables involved and 
fully qualify the fields so there's no ambiguity on which column comes from which table.

This matters here because: What table is building_Id in?

If offices, then we may have to eliminate the where clause as a whole and have a "AND" on the join.  Otherwise, the where clause will negate the left join making it behave like an inner join.

Why... the join occurs first creating offices with a NULL building_ID for some personnel.  Then the where clause runs eliminating the NULL records as they don't match the $Session[Building_ID].  so we just made the left join act an inner if building is on the offices table.

now if building is on the personnel table.... then it won't matter and leaving it in the where clause is fine.

Answer (score 0):

For your task you should use `LEFT JOIN` which will return you table below. `LEFT JOIN` takes whats on the left (personnel) and joins whats on the right (offices) and if there is no pair for a record from table on the left, then it will just return Null where values will be missing.

```
SELECT * 
FROM personnel 
LEFT JOIN offices ON offices.office_id=personnel.office_id 
WHERE building_id=$SESSION[building_id] 
ORDER BY last_name

|Jack | Building1 | Office1
|John | Building1 | Office2
|Jill | Building1 | Null
|Judy | Building1 | Office3
|Jenn | Building1 | Office4
```

Also make sure to use correct sequence of SQL operators: SELECT ... FROM ... [LEFT / RIGHT JOIN ... ON ...] WHERE ... GROUP BY ...